# Possible capacitor plague - need help identifying

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, capacitor

I've been having some PC power issues lately, and I think I've tracked it down to a bad power supply. Lately, when I'm on my PC it will often restart without warning, displaying "Hypertransport sync flood error occurred last boot." once POST finishes. I've googled the error, but can't come to a definitive conclusion as to what's causing it. I've seen posts suggesting that it might be a power supply issue, but nothing conclusive.

```
Here's what I've done so far:
-I haven't installed anything suspect within the last 3 months.
-I do overclock just a tiny bit, so I tried raising the voltages a little. That didn't work so I brought both CPU multiplier and voltages all back to their default settings, but that didn't solve the problem either.
 The problem still occurs.
-AV scanned the whole system, nothing suspect.
-I suspected that it might be a bad power supply so I cracked that open and found    
 the following:
```

[image: Possible cap plague]

I *think* it might be cap plague, but I'm not sure. It looks more like glue TBH. Could someone help me figure out what might be wrong with this PC?

EDIT: Sometimes, after these restarts, I noticed that the GPU fan doesn't spin up, and the single rear case fan that just happens to be connected to the same molex Y-cable as the GFX card doesn't spin up either. Anything to that?

EDIT 2: I do use the system quite heavily, but I don't know how that will factor into this. I often play Diablo 3 and EVE Online at the same time, frequently alt-tabbing between the two. I also have Firefox open in the background, sometimes with several tabs, and if I feel like it, I'll mute the in-game sound and open foobar2000 for better music. Could it be that I'm just pushing this thing too hard?

EDIT 3: I also noticed something odd. Right before I experience these restarts, my monitor would suffer from very faint lines of static moving across the screen. The monitor is still very much useable, but it is very annoying. Following the restart it disappears, and then would gradually re-appear over the next few days, and then restarts again. I find it to be very odd.

System specs for good measure:

Orion 600 W PSU
AMD Athlon II X3 440 (overclocked to 3.14 ghZ, raised the CPU multiplier to x13 from x10)
MSI G40-775 motherboard
1 GB inno3D GTX 550 ti
4 GB DDR3 RAM
500 GB Samsung SATA HD

Comment: Capacitor leakage looks like brown crusty stuff.  Solid "hard" white stuff is glue.  Busted caps from the bottom would usually be tilted.

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The white stuff is just a paste to hold everything in place and help dissipate some heat/ That looks normal.

When Overclocking, the components *may* already be damaged beyond repair, even if it was "just a little bit". Although I can't find the source, Intel did have a report showing that overclocking lowers the life expectancy of CPUs by as much as 80% (again, I can't remember the source, but I'll try to find it again).

I suspect it may be something else though. How old is the power supply? Some lower-end power supplies can lose as much as 20% of their capacitance every year or so when in use.

**Edit**: Seeing your edits, I would assume it's the graphics card. I always try to use the PCIe power connectors from the power supply over any sort of Molex-to-PCIe adapters, as the amperage will usually be affected with those make shift adapters. Do you have the two PCIe adapters it requires? Try using those. If you NEED to use the adapters, make sure they're plugged into different "rails" of power

```
IE
PSU --+---M--+
      |      +---PCIe
      +---M--+

Instead of:
PSU --+---M-----M
          |     |
          +-----+---PCIe
```

Comment: Everything is less than 1.5 years old. So fairly new, I'd say. RE: Overclocking, should I stop with what i"m doing and bring it back down to stock speeds? I'd like to note that I made this post and the original post from the computer that's being affected. It still works, it just restarts from time to time.

Comment: @cornjuliox See edits

Comment: The GTX 550 ti only has one PCI-e power connector. It just so happens that As I was looking at one of the power conectors I noticed that the plastic on the molex connector had melted....brb

Comment: !!!! Cool... Post a picture!

Comment: ... 20 minutes and no response... Did you kill your computer? I hope not

Comment: No, thankfully my computer is responsive. However, I did have to pull a Y-shaped molex cable out of my PC. Upon closer inspection, the plastic on one of the male connectors and the female connector had melted on the side, and one of the yellow wires had black scorch marks on both tips. Could this be the source of my problem?

Comment: So, if I understand your suggestion right, does that mean I should assign a single wire from the power supply chiefly for the gfx card, and not share it with anything else?

Comment: No, split the power between two sets of Molex connections